# Delete after Insert trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create after insert trigger to delete a row from table whenever I insert the same row in the opposite table using the ID

But it doesn't work

```
Create Trigger [dbo].[MeritedDeceased] On [dbo].[Deceased]
After Insert
As
Begin
Delete From dbo.Merited Where dbo.Deceased.ID = dbo.Merited.ID
End
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not providing any information about what is happening. In your trigger you should be referring to the inserted virtual table or you are going to be deleting a LOT more data than you anticipate.

Comment: I want to delete the entire row,

Should I create a view, or what?

Comment: Delete what row? We can't see your screen and have no idea what you are trying to do. And how would a view help here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you mean to do something like this (maybe)...

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[MeritedDeceased] ON [dbo].[Deceased]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE M
    FROM [dbo].[MeritedDeceased] M
    INNER JOIN Inserted I
        ON I.ID = M.ID
    ;
END
;
```

Translation: Every time a row is inserted into `dbo.Deceased`, delete any rows with the same (inserted) ID from `dbo.MeritedDeceased`.

FYI, this `TRIGGER` won't just delete one row, but also a batch of rows that were inserted together.  If that's what you want, then this should help.

Comment: This was what I was guessing as well but you were faster on the keys. :)

Comment: @SeanLange I type quickly.  It's one of my few redeeming qualities :)
Didn't mean to steal it away from you.  We'll see - maybe the OP wants something altogether different.

Comment: LOL no such thing as "stealing" it. You typed up a very valid solution and deserve all the credit for posting it. Well done!!

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks to you both :D

Comment: Just happy to help, Hady.  
@SeanLange Thanks for the support.  I love this community...